# Reading inappropriate word/symbol from YouTube caption in R

Tags: r, string, youtube, grepl, caption

I have data from YouTube captions. Some inappropriate words are shown by [Â __Â ] in excel file. When I read the data in R it appears as [ __ ]. I am using str_contains in order to identify any inappropriate words in the text but it isn't able to identify [ __ ] in R. grepl is also not helping my cause.

I will appreciate any help.

```
text <- "oh well holy [ __ ] this is right there is"
str_contains("[ __ ]", text)
```

Comment: What library does the `str_contains` function come from? It may be that you have the arguments the wrong way around _i.e._ string first, then the pattern. There could be character encoding issues too.

Answer (score 0):

Neil was right, the parameters were the wrong way around:

```
pacman::p_load(sjmisc)
text <- "oh well holy [ __ ] this is right there is"
pattern <- "[ __ ]"
str_contains(pattern, text) # FALSE
str_contains(text, pattern) # TRUE
```